# Postgres distinct inner join (one to many) with n constraints on joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, where-clause, having-clause

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to perform a Postgres query.

I have 2 tables

- Orders (id, order_name)
- Items (id, order_id, item_name)

Each order in the orders table has between 1 and n items listed in the items table.

What I want is to perform a query that returns all order that contains item Burger, item Pizza and item Coke.

Is the call below the best way to do such query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (orders.id)
   orders.id
FROM orders
INNER JOIN items i1 on orders.id = i1.order_id
INNER JOIN items i2 on orders.id = i2.order_id
INNER JOIN items i3 on orders.id = i3.order_id
WHERE i1.item_name = 'Burger'
AND i2.item_name = 'Fries'
AND i3.item_name = 'Coke'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach works, and should be relatively efficient. Assuming that there are no duplicate order id / item names, you can remove `distinct` from the other query, which avoids unecessary work.

You could also use aggregation. It involves less additional typing when the number of items increases:

```
select o.*
from orders o
inner join items i on i.order_id = o.id
where i.item_name in ('Burger', 'Fries', 'Coke')  -- any of the three items
group by o.order_id
having count(*) = 3                               -- all items match
```

Again, this assumes no duplicates in items; else, you need `having count(distinct i.item_name) = 3` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation GMB!
Do you have an idea of your query's performance given that it does aggregation?

Comment: @johnson23: it is hard to tell beforehand. You would need to assess this against your real data.